# what will be time complexity of relation T(n)=nT(n-1)+n

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

WHAT will be time complexity of relation T(n)=nT(n-1)+n
in my prog something like this

```
f(int n)
{
    c++;
    if(n>0)
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            f(n-1);
}
```

i took a counter to count how many time function called
it gives answer between n to n!
thanks.

Comment: There is no `+n` part should be.

Comment: The relation ``T(n) = n * T(n-1)`` is the factorial of n. So the time complexity should be ``O(n!)``.
 (I've ignored the ``+n`` because the code doesn't this computation...but the result is the same because ``n`` is too small with respect to ``n!``)

Comment: it's funny to see *3* almost identical answers for a question with a negative score.

Comment: @sds, yes, I think we like hairsplitting on trivial cpu cycles.

Comment: the counter c is showing value according to relation n*T(n-1)+n i.e e*n!     then why +n part is wrong, do we not count i++ part of loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can list out a few terms

```
T(0) = 0
T(1) = 1 * 0 + 1
T(2) = 2 * 1 + 2 = 4
T(3) = 3 * 4 + 3 = 15
T(4) = 4 * 15 + 4 = 64
...
```

We can note a couple of things. First, the function grows more quickly than n!; it starts out smaller than it (at n=0), catches up (at n=1) and surpasses it (at n>=2). So we know that a lower bound is n!.

Now, we need the upper bound. We can notice one thing: T(n) = nT(n-1) + n < nT(n-1) + nT(n-1) for all sufficiently large n (n >= 2, I think). But we can easily show that T(n) = nT(n-1) is a recurrence relation for n!, so we know that a recurrence relation for T(n) = nT(n-1) + nT(n-1) = 2nT(n-1) is (n!)(2^n). Can we do better?

I propose that we can. We can show that for any c > 0, T(n) = nT(n-1) + n < nT(n-1) + cnT(n-1) for sufficiently large values of n. We already know that T(n-1) is bounded below by (n-1)!; so, if we take c = n/(n-1)! we recover exactly our expression and we know that an upper bound is (c^n)(n!). What is the limit of c as n goes to infinity? 0. What is the maximum value assumed by [n/(n-1)!]^n?

Good luck computing that. Wolfram Alpha makes it fairly clear that the maximum value assumed by this function is around 5 or 6 for n ~ 2.5. Assuming you are convinced by that, what's the takeaway?

n! < T(n) < ~6n! for all n. n! is the Theta-bound for your recurrence.

Comment: I don't think `T(2) = 2 * 1 + 2`. There is one initial call, e.g. from `main`. From then on the function is called `n` times and recurses. You may not extrapolate this +1 into +2, +3, +4,... +`n`

Comment: ...which means that `T(0) = 0 + 1`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Upon actually reading the code snippet, I'd agree you're right about the relationship not being what's in the title. However - I'd go on to argue the real relationship is more like `T(n) = a + bn + cnT(n-1)`, leaving alone squabbling about what the constants should be.

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks the `+n` part of the recursion, so I assume that the code is wrong and the recursion

```
T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n
```

is correct.

Let `f(n)=T(n)/n!`, then

```
f(n) = T(n)/n! = n(T(n-1)+1)/n! 
     = T(n-1)/(n-1)! + 1/(n-1)!
     = f(n-1) +  1/(n-1)!
     = sum(1,n-1, 1/k!)
     ~ e
```

Thus `T(n) ~ e*n!`.

Comment: What do you mean with "`+n`" part? The code recurses fine.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: there is no operation which takes time `n` in the code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie in the title is specified the relation ``T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n``, but the example code doesn't justify the ``+n``.

Comment: Ah..yes, he says that in the title.

Comment: @sds Thanks, I missed the outer parenthesis.

Comment: @vinaynegi: usually trivial arithmetics is ignored because its cost is, well, trivial.

Comment: I got confused because of value of counter 'c' giving value according to relation nT(n-1)+n, i.e e*n! ... ???

Answer (score -1):

The function is called

```
n*f(n-1)
```

times. Replacing `f(n-1)` with this definition gives

```
n*((n-1)*f(n-2)
```

Replacing again gives:

```
n*((n-1)*((n-2)*f(n-3)))
```

Removing brackets:

```
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...(1)
```

This gives:

```
n= 3: 3*2*1 = 6
n= 4: 4*3*2*1 = 24
n= 5: 5*4*3*2*1 = 120
```

which is `n!`.

Comment: factorial of ``n``? :-)