# what would be time complexity of this recursive function

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to find time complexity of this chunk, is it O(n!) or O(2^n), how??

```
void fun(int n)
{
    int i;
    count++;
    if(n>0)
    {
        for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        fun(n-i);
    }
}
```

I tried it for diff values of n and `count` giving value acc. to `2^n`
??

thanks

Comment: Don't you think you should do your homework yourself? Note the function is useless, as it has no side-effects and does not yield anything. It might have O(1).

Comment: It's not homework. it is calling in 2^n steps, but not sure is it its time complexity. And why down vote?

Comment: @Olaf `count++` has a side effect.

Comment: Surely you can figure this out from trying different values of `n` input and looking at the value of `count` output.

Comment: @Olaf no mean to downvote!!

Comment: Ah! This is homework with some professor throwing this assignment around. There is already an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634026/what-will-be-time-complexity-of-relation-tn-ntn-1n

Comment: @vinaynegi: Coincidence does not mean causality. Critique in a comment does not imply that person downvoted! Anyway, the DVs (notice the plural!) are well rectified.

Comment: @amit: I see. Yes, you are right. Sorry I overlooked that. It is "unexpected" and makes the question incomplete. (I still suspect `count` is just for some statistics)

Comment: @MartinJames: Why not dup-close then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every call of T(n), invokes `T(n-1), T(n-2), ..., T(1)`.

This gives us the complexity function of:

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + .... + T(1)
```

If we will use induction, and hypothesis `T(k) <= c*2^k` for any `k < n` and for some constant `c` (and after properly checking `T(1) = 1 <= 2^1`, we get:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + ... + T(1) + 1 = 
     = c*2^(n-1) + c*2^(n-2) + ... + c*2^1 + 2^0  <= 
    <= c*(2^n - 1) <= c*2^n
```

The last equality is from sum of geometric series.

Thus, we can conclude `T(n)` is in `Theta(2^n)`

Comment: thanks,and in term of O( ) could we write it O(2^n) ..?

Comment: @vinaynegi Everything that is in `Theta(f(n))` is also `O(f(n))`, so yes. It is indeed `O(2^n)`.